# 0th order accuracy central difference?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Looking at [central difference coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient), there is a clear pattern on the order of accuracy and the number of coefficients. For the first derivative with a 3pt stencil, the coefficients are given by $\{-1/2,0,1/2\}$ and the order of accuracy is $O(\delta)^2$.

If I were to free up the coefficients, while retaining the antisymmetry, such that the coefficients become $\{-a,0,a\}$, would the order of accuracy drop to $O(\delta)^0$, a constant? From what I gather, the error analysis at this level would be related to the mean value theorem? How would I formulate the error analysis in relation to the choice of the coefficient $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the Taylor series of your function
$$
  f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+O(\delta^3).
$$
(The $O(\delta^3)$ can be made more rigorous using Taylor's theorem as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/888280/197161)). Then $f'(0)=c_1$, so
$$
  \frac{-af(-\delta)+af(\delta)}{\delta}
    =2ac_1+O(\delta^2)
    =f'(0)+(2a-1)c_1+O(\delta^2).
$$
Taking $a=\frac12$, this is $f'(0)+O(\delta^2)$, but otherwise the difference is of constant order as you say.

Comment: I follow you...thanks for the clear explanation on the reasoning for the constant order of error and showing where it comes from.